# CMS wyswig images wrong path

Tags: magento2, image, cms

In blocks or cms pages I'm trying to add an image (Magento 2). But after selecting an image and choosing insert (from insert image popup) image URL of the image is wysiwyg/image.jpg and preview is missing. I think it should be followed by pub/media. How fix this, it is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

The path is like `<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/The_Office.png"}}" alt="" />`
The path `pub/media` will be identify by `media url`.
Now make sure there will not any space between path otherwise you can not see the preview in the editor.